# Generate static files of specific nodes with Tome

Tags: 9

I'm looking for a way to generate a static version of specified nodes ( in my case they are book nodes pages).

I want to do it periodically in my custom Drupal cronjob,

most of the Drupal static modules are obsolete and there is no version for **Drupal 9.**

I found [TOME](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/tome) module but looks like it's mostly for generating full website static generation through admin panel or `drush` command line.

I tried `drush tome:static-export-path /mybookpath --uri=localhost:8080` but it's blindly going through all the links on the pages and download all of them.

with digging more into the documentation I found [this](https://tome.fyi/docs/technical/api/) which is good to use tome services.  in this case, there is no URI parameter option( it's only available for drush command) and it does not replace URLs ( image,link, style ( css) urls) and use the main version.

```
    <?php

/** @var \Drupal\tome_static\StaticGeneratorInterface $static */
$static = \Drupal::service('tome_static.generator');

/** @var \Drupal\tome_static\RequestPreparer $request_preparer */
$request_preparer = \Drupal::service('tome_static.request_preparer');

// Prepare for a new request. This is necessary so that static caches in Drupal
// can be reset between multiple requests in one bootstrap.
$request_preparer->prepareForRequest();

// Request an arbitrary path. "$invoke_paths" at this point is anything that
// needs to be copied (an existing file) or requested (an image derivative,
// other paths, etc.)
$invoke_paths = $static->requestPath('/foo');

// Export paths will try to copy or remove as many paths as possible without
// making a new internal request.
$invoke_paths = $static->exportPaths($invoke_paths);

// The remaining invoke paths need to be handled in new requests.
foreach ($invoke_paths as $path) {
  // Since we are only trying to export one path, restrict new requests to
  // paths with extensions, which are probably RSS feeds and image derivatives.
  if (pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) {
    $request_preparer->prepareForRequest();
    // This could return more paths, but we're ignoring that for simplicity.
    $static->requestPath($path);
  }
}
```

**My question:** What is the best solution to generate static HTML files will all assets of specific Drupal nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Tome and with the following function I implement custom path fetching

```
public static function storeFileLocally($uri) {
$base_url = "http://localhost:8080";
$path = $uri;
/** @var \Drupal\tome_static\StaticGeneratorInterface $static */
$static = \Drupal::service('tome_static.generator');

/** @var \Drupal\tome_static\RequestPreparer $request_preparer */
$request_preparer = \Drupal::service('tome_static.request_preparer');

TomeStaticHelper::setBaseUrl(\Drupal::request(), $base_url);

$request_preparer->prepareForRequest();
$invoke_paths = $static->requestPath($path);

$invoke_paths = $static->exportPaths($invoke_paths);

foreach ($invoke_paths as $path) {
  if (pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) {
    $request_preparer->prepareForRequest();
    $static->requestPath($path);
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can always recreate static pages with `wget`.

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --show-progress --content-disposition http://example.edu
```

This will create a copy of the entire site. I believe you can adjust the URL to be a specific node.

Comment: thanks for your attention. I tried it but it goes through all the links on the page.

Comment: I'm looking for more drupal base solution but ok .I can wrapp it in drupal command.